# Order by duplicate amount in a list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have this class:

```
class Cell
{
    string keyword;
    double bkgColor;
    double keywordColor;
}
```

I have a list of this class and I want to order it by duplicates of bkgColor using linq.
For example: Keywords with background color that has the most keywords assigned, would be at the start of the list etc.

Evey answer is highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you familiar with GroupBy in LINQ? You could group and order by count of items in the group.

Comment: how do we know which list element have the most keywords assigned according to your class ?

Comment: @RayaneStaszewski OP says there exists "...a list of this class..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that keyword, bkgColor and keywordColor are public properties of the class Cell. You can use this linq

```
var result = cells.GroupBy(c => c.bkgColor)
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
            .SelectMany(g => g.Select(c => c));
```

Comment: That won't order by count of bkgColor which is stated as a requirement

Comment: @Crowcoder fixed it. It should work

Comment: No, you have to order by g.Count()

Comment: I'm quite sure you can simplify this by removing the whole `.Select()` statement and removing the `.Cell` part of your `.SelectMany()` statement :) [Edit: and using `.Count()` rather than `.Count`, as Crowcoder states)]

Comment: OP can play around it. It is just to give him an idea.